# Naming after the Patriarchs/Matriarchs and Biblical heroes

Tags: names, historical-figures, statistics

Nowadays it is very common for Jews to name their children after the Patriarchs, Matriarchs, and Biblical heroes.

But it doesn't seem (to me) as though this was very common until well into the period of the Rishonim.

I base my assumption upon the distinct lack of famous Jewish leaders with such names as Avraham, David, Moshe, Aharon, and many others prior to that period*.

While I cannot claim to have convincing evidence that it was rare before the era of the Rishonim for Jews to name their children after the 3 Patriarchs, and it would certainly be odd if the Talmud, a collection of male-dominated discussions, randomly mentioned that, oh, by the way, our mothers and sisters are mostly named after the 4 Matriarchs and Dinah, I'd expect that, if there were a high incidence of naming children after these major figures, there would also be a higher incidence of major leaders appearing in literature, spanning Na"Ch through the Geonic era, bearing those names.

Assuming my observation is correct, when did the trend begin to change, and was there a reason people largely did not name their children after these heroes, maybe out of Kavod, for example, like, LeHavdil, heroic sports figures having their jersey numbers retired by their teams?

<sub>*I do have to concede that there are some notable exceptions, including several Tannaim named Yose, Yehoshua', and Yehudah (among others).
Another major exception was the infamous Menashe, who, I can only assume, was named after the much more positive role-model that was the son of Yosef born in Egypt.
There are also other Tannaim named after some lesser characters mentioned in the Torah, such as El'azar, and even the important (quasi-)villain Yishma'el.</sub>

Comment: Another possible counterexample: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/306/are-the-names-akiva-and-yaakov-related On Yishma'el: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/73/naming-after-bad-people/74#74

Comment: @IsaacMoses, argh, I actually meant to include 'Akiva. I have been sufficiently convinced in the past that it could be a nickname for Ya'akov that I deliberately did not include it in my sentence beginning "I base my assumption."

Comment: @SethJ As R' 'Akiva famously taught us, it's never too late.

Comment: Your question is stronger if you limit it to tanach times. There are very very few duplicate names (among famous people) in tanach. (Menashe hamelech and yehoshua hakohein hagadol come to mind.)

Comment: @IsaacMoses There are plenty of Chazal named after Ya'akov Avinu, including: Rabbi Ya'akov bar Idi, Rav Acha bar Ya'akov, Rav Ya'akov bar Acha, Rav Ya'akov miNahar P'kod, Rav Ya'akov b'reih d'vas Sh'mu'el, Rav Ya'akov b'reih d'vas Ya'akov, Rav Ya'akov bar Giyuri, Rabbi Ya'akov bar Nachmani, Rabbi Eli'ezer ben Ya'akov, and Rav Ya'akov bar Abba.

Comment: ... Not to mention Rabbi Ya'akov (the Tanna), Rabbi Ya'akov ben Chananaya, Rabbi Ya'akov Ish K'far Chananya, and Rabbi Ya'akov ben Kurshai.

Comment: @DoubleAA, you make a good point, but the pool is smaller, and the time span is shorter. This way, although there are more individual exceptions, I don't believe the number of exceptions disproves the premise, since that the incidence does not seem any greater, given the greater span of generations and the larger pool of leaders.

Comment: highly related (but the inverse): http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3252/jewish-names-that-are-not-common

Comment: Another Tanach example is Yishmael ben Netanya, the murderer of Gedaliah ben Achikam.

Comment: [Numbers 13:7](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0413.htm#7)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by well into the period of the Rishonim.  Offhand, most of the 11th, 12th, and early 13th century Rishonim I can think of had Biblical names. Rif; Yitzchak, Ri Migash; Yosef, Rambam; Moshe, Rashi; Shlomo, Rabbenu Tam; Yaakov, Ri (Hazaken); Yitzchak, Ramban; Moshe, Rahba; Sh'lomo, Rashbam; Sh'muel, Raavad; Avraham.

Comment: @Seth I guess I reminded you about this question when I upvoted it this morning?:) I was going to ask something similar. I still might.

Comment: @user6591, yup. Go right ahead.

Comment: Don't forget about the Amoraim Shmuel, Levi, R' Yosef, R' Yehoshua Ben Levi and his father, R' Doniel bar Ketina, R' Nachman, Chizkiyah and Yehudah sons of Chiya, R' Chiya bar Yosef's father, R' Yehudah bar Yechezkel and his father, R' Shimon Ben Lakish, R' Chagai, the grandmother of Rabbah bar bar Chanah... I almost feel like the question's invalid because of how many Amoraim and Tannaim actually have names from Tanach.

Comment: @DonielF, see my response to DoubleAA above. I don't know that those exceptions disprove my observation, or strengthen it by limiting it. Perhaps there were biblical names used with greater frequency than I thought, but now it seems like some names were strictly off-limits (eg., Avraham and Moshe; perhaps others?). Maybe my question was off in its focus, and maybe it is stronger if, instead of broadly including biblical heroes, it is limited to biblical super-heroes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Chida notes that no Tannaim or Amoraim were named Avraham (however, see mention of אברם חוזאה in *Gittin* 50a). The quote from the Chida follows (Shem ha-Gedolim in his entry for Mar R. Avraham Gaon):

וראה זה חדש שלא מצינו בתנאים שבמשנה והבריתא תנא ששמו אברהם וגם מאמוראים לא מצאתי כעת בס' יוחסין... גם שם יצחק בתנאים שבמשנה לא יש מי ששמו יצחק, אך בבריתא ובזוהר הקדוש יש, ובאמוראים הרבה יש ששמם יצחק, ובשם יעקב יש זכר במשנה ובבריתא והרבה בש"ס, ומהגאונים ואילך נשתרבבו שמות אברהם יצחק ויעקב בגאונים וברבנים ובכל המון ישראל עד היום הזה. וגם באות מם להלן (עי' רב משה גאון) הבאתי שמצאתי בכ"י מי שהפליא שלא היה בתנאים ואמוראים מי שנקרא משה עד הגאונים ע"ש.

In his entry for R. Moshe Gaon, the Chida likewise notes the absence of Tannaim and Amoraim named Moshe (though note the name of Rav Huna's father, משה בר עצרי, mentioned in *Arachin* 23a). The Chida writes:

מצאתי כתוב בס' כ"י לא היה שום תנא או אמורא שנקרא משה והוא פלא וסוד. והיינו דאמרי אנשי על הרמב"ם, ממשה ועד משה וכו' שלא היה תנא או אמורא שנקרא משה, עכ"ד

The Maharatz Chajes (*Gittin* 50a) thinks it is merely a coincidence that Chazal didn't mention rabbis with certain famous Biblical names:

בכל זאת לא מצינו בזמן התנאים והאמוראים שהיו נקראים על שם אבותינו...אהרן וגד ואשר דוד ושלמה, ובלא ספק דרק מקרה קרה שלא היו חכמים בזמניהם שיהיו נקראים בשם זה, או שלא היה לחז"ל לספר מאנשי זמנם אשר היה שמם כן, כמו שמצינו (קידושין ל.) זבולון בן דן תלמיד שמואל, הנה לא מצינו בשום מקום שיהיה איש בזמן התנאים והאמוראים ששמו זבולון או דן רק במקום זה, ובכ"ז מוכח מכאן דמ"מ היו נקראים גם בזמנם בשם זה, וצא ולמד גם על שאר שמות שלא נזכרו במשנה ותלמוד אינו בכוונה אלא ע"פ מקרה.

However, [R. Nosson Gestetner](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A0%D7%AA%D7%9F_%D7%92%D7%A9%D7%98%D7%98%D7%A0%D7%A8), after citing the Chida, [suggests](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=936&st=&pgnum=15&hilite=) that, as with Moshe, the souls of Avraham, Aharon, David, and Shlomo encompass the souls of all Jews and represent the transmission of the Torah in its entirety. Since the rabbis of the Talmud established the foundations of the Oral Law, each of them could deservedly be called by these names (as in the instance of Rav Safra calling Rava the name Moshe). R. Gestetner therefore suggests that, to distinguish the rabbis from one another, none of them were called by these names:

והנה כתב האריז"ל, "כללות כל הנשמות הם ששים רבוא, והתורה היא שורש הנשמות בישראל, ולכן יש כנגדם ששים רבוא פירושים, אשר כפי כל פירוש מן הששים רבוא משם נתהוה שורש נשמה אחת מישראל, ולעתיד לבוא כל אחד ואחד יקרא את התורה כפי הפירוש המגיע לשורשו...ונשמת משה רבינו ע"ה היתה כוללת כל הששים רבוא, ולכן ידע כל הששים רבוא פירושים"... ומעתה נראה לומר דגם חכמי המשנה והגמרא שהעמידו את יסודות תורה שבעל פה, כללו בתוכם את נשמת משה רבינו ע"ה...ולכן מצינו בגמ' (שבת קא:) דאמר ליה רב ספרא לרבא משה שפיר קאמרת...והיינו כי כל חכמי הש"ס הם בבחינת משה רבינו שכללו את כל התורה כולה, ולכן לא נקראו בשם מיוחד משה כי שם זה לא סגי להבדילם איש מחבירו, דהא כל אחד מהם הוא בבחינת משה, וכולם ביחד הם בבחינת משה רבינו, אבל ניתן להם שם אחר המייחד את כל אחד מחבירו לפי בחינתו...ולפי דרך זה יש לומר גם טעם שלא מצינו בין חכמי המשנה והגמרא שמות של אברהם אבינו ואהרן ודוד ושלמה, כי נשמותיהם היו גם כן נשמות כוללות...

Comment: It would be nice to get a translation, even a loose one... I guess R' Gestetner in the name of the Ari claims that souls of Moshe, Avraham, Dovid and Shlomo were root souls, and all tannaim and amoraim had some aspect of (e.g.) Moshe in them,  so they would not name anyone with those names as it was not particular enough to distinguish an individual.

Comment: I guess something changed at the time of R' Moshe Gaon and the Rambam. I wonder what it was...

Comment: @gt6989b the jooneem and rambam did not believe in jeeljuleem. Therefore what changed was that the ari and his posses changed the meaning of what the jamoro meant and not what it really meant.

Comment: R' Gestetner's explanation also accounts for the lack of those named "Yisrael".