# Why are there no Tanaaim or Amoraaim with the names Avraham or Moshe?

Tags: names, talmud-gemara, mishna

I heard this question posed a few days ago, and I've been wondering about it ever since. Why are there no Tanaaim or Amoraaim in the Mishnah or Gemara with the names Avraham or Moshe (or David, for that matter, although there might be just one or two very minor ones with the name David in particular).

Anyone have any insight into this?

Comment: Why would you think there would be Tannaim with that name?

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9591&hilite=9814b4f0-632a-408f-a591-6192f4099028&st=%D7%94%D7%99%D7%94+%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9D+%D7%AA%D7%A0%D7%90+%D7%90%D7%95+%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%90+%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%A7%D7%94%D7%90+%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%94+%D7%95%D7%94%D7%95%D7%90&pgnum=563

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=50101&hilite=341519a8-d9f2-4607-883a-7b0366887647&st=%D7%94%D7%99%D7%94+%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9D+%D7%AA%D7%A0%D7%90+%D7%90%D7%95+%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%90+%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%A7%D7%94%D7%90+%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%94+%D7%95%D7%94%D7%95%D7%90&pgnum=149

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_49834_443.pdf

Comment: Related (dupe?): http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28170/5

Comment: answered there: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/31929/1012