# Names of Tanaim and Amoraim

Tags: names, historical-figures, tannaim, amoroim

A friend mentioned to me that there are no Tanaim or Amoraim named Avraham, Moshe or Dovid and that there was "some torah" on this fact, but he couldn't remember what it was. Is there any source for this idea?

Comment: It's false. There were people with those names. See [Gittin 50a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=19&daf=50&format=pdf) [Erchin 23a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=33&daf=23&format=pdf) and some versions of Yevamot 115b.

Comment: @DoubleAA Avram is not the same as Avraham, and Moshe in Erchin seems to be related to an Amora, but not himself an Amora.

Comment: answers to your question are found here: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/31929/603

Comment: @Menachem I think you are right. Why not post that as an answer?

Comment: Plenty of Yaakov's and Yitzchak's and Shimon's and Yehudah's. So it has nothing to do with names from Tanach.

Answer (score 1):

Different names are popular in different time periods. Add to that that most of the later amoraim had non-hebrew names.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @sabbahillel It depends how you define "some Torah".

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Sara!