# Why does the Gemara reference R' Yaakov in an odd way?

Tags: talmud-gemara, language, tractate-sotah

In Sotah 46a, it says the following:

> ***אָמַר לְהוּ הַהוּא מֵרַבָנָן ור׳ יַעֲקבֹ שְמֵיהּ לְדִידִי*** מְפָרְשָא לִי מִינֵּיהּ דְרַבִי יוֹחָנָן מְשִיכַת עוֹל לְרָחְבוֹ טֶפַח
>
> ***One of the rabbis said to them, and his name was Rabbi Yaakov***,  The statement of Rabbi Yochanan was explained to me as meaning: Drawing by a yoke to the extent of a handbreadth in its breadth.

Why does the Gemara refer to R' Yaakov in this odd fashion?

Comment: I would appreciate if anyone could add other places where R' yakov is mentioned in this way; my rabbi said he is referred to like this in all of talmud

Comment: See [Shabbos 134b](https://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=134b&format=text), ['Eruvin 80a](https://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=3&daf=80&format=text), Kiddushin [13a](https://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=20&daf=13&format=text) and [55a](https://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=20&daf=55&format=text), [Bava Kama 94b](https://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=21&daf=94b&format=text), ['Avoda Zara 75b](https://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=27&daf=75b&format=text) (cf. Tanchuma on Chukas), [Chullin 76a](https://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=31&daf=76&format=text)

Comment: Though R' Ya'akov is the most frequent one introduced this way, he isn't the only one. Rav Tavus, for instance, is introduced this way in a couple places [*Bava M'tzi'a* 49a](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Metzia.49a.16?lang=bi) (see also *Sanhedrin* 97a): "אמר לי ההוא מרבנן ורב טבות שמיה ואמרי לה רב שמואל בר זוטרא שמיה דאי הוו יהבי ליה כל חללא דעלמא לא הוי קא משני בדבוריה". [This thread](https://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?t=56972) cites R' Chaim Kanievsky as saying that it means the amora who quoted the teaching didn't know who said it, but the Sages knew and added it in.

Comment: See [this article](https://daf-yomi.com/DYItemDetails.aspx?itemId=32102) for a discussion of the topic. R' Ya'akov was a student of Rabbi Yochanan, so that should help identify [which R' Ya'akov](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28170/naming-after-the-patriarchs-matriarchs-and-biblical-heroes#comment67188_28170) it is. Our girsa of the gemara in Chullin refers to him as "Rav Ya'akov", while one girsa of the Ran (on Shabbos) interestingly refers to him as R' Akiva.

Comment: Avodah Zarah 28b, Avodah Zarah 75b, Chullin 76a, Chullin 98a, Shabbat 134b, Eruvin 80a, Kiddushin 13a, Kiddushin 55a, Bava Kamma 94b, Menachot 17a (Baruch Hashem for technology). @Fred, your comment that seems to contain the correct answer - can you post it as one for posterity?

Comment: Thank you for the background information @Fred. Could you translate the article? thx